# Materialize Datepicker prevent end date before start date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timepicker, materialize

For Materialize datepicker, I have found the min and max options for Materialize datepicker, but do not know how to set two datepickers used in conjunction with each other as follows:

1. User selects a start date.
2. User now must select an end date, but should not be able to select a date before the start date.
3. Should the user select the end date first, he/she should not be able to select a start date after that end date.

I am not a javascript programmer, so not sure how to even start this. From my guesses, I would need to put some code in the onSet event of each datepicker.

I am also trying to do the same for the timepicker: http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/jquery.html.

Can someone please assist with this code or another solution?

Comment: For now, I have done server-side validation upon form submit. Works, but is not quite what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settled for server side validation. There seems to be no way to do this on client side with the materialize plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The Materialize Date Picker uses [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/), which offers the following solution: http://codepen.io/amsul/pen/nGckA

```
var from_$input = $('#input_from').pickadate(),
    from_picker = from_$input.pickadate('picker')

var to_$input = $('#input_to').pickadate(),
    to_picker = to_$input.pickadate('picker')


// Check if there’s a “from” or “to” date to start with.
if ( from_picker.get('value') ) {
  to_picker.set('min', from_picker.get('select'))
}
if ( to_picker.get('value') ) {
  from_picker.set('max', to_picker.get('select'))
}

// When something is selected, update the “from” and “to” limits.
from_picker.on('set', function(event) {
  if ( event.select ) {
    to_picker.set('min', from_picker.get('select'))    
  }
  else if ( 'clear' in event ) {
    to_picker.set('min', false)
  }
})
to_picker.on('set', function(event) {
  if ( event.select ) {
    from_picker.set('max', to_picker.get('select'))
  }
  else if ( 'clear' in event ) {
    from_picker.set('max', false)
  }
})
```

You can add this to the page where the datepickers are being used - just be sure to update the two ids in the example (`#input_from` and `#input_to`) to match the ids of your start & end datepickers.

Comment: Unsure why the user accepted his own answer, since he was offering for something completely different. Your answer was perfect, and allowed me to get much more custom.

Answer (score 0):

The below code does it on client side.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        closeOnSelect: true,
        closeOnClear: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onSet: function (ele) {
           if(ele.select){
                  this.close();
           }

            var d1 = $('#startdate').val();
            var d2 = $('#enddate').val();

            var date1 = new Date(d1);
            var date2 = new Date(d2);

           var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
           var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

            if((date2_ms -date1_ms ) <0 )
            {
              alert('End date cannot be a previous date!');
              $('#startdate').val(d2);  

            }

        }

      });
```

Comment: Thank you! I see your solution, but I was actually looking for not being able to select the date in the first place :-)